# New Relic Micrometer instrumentation Error Rate dashboards for Open Telemetry are queried incorrectly

Tags: newrelic, open-telemetry, micrometer, spring-micrometer, otlp-grpc

I wanted to configure Micrometer with New Relic Open Telemetry.
I followed instructions from the "Archival note" section of   https://github.com/newrelic/micrometer-registry-newrelic

My dependencies:

```kotlin
    platform("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-bom:1.28.0")
    implementation("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-api")
    implementation("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-sdk")
    implementation("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp")
    implementation("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-prometheus:1.28.0-alpha")
    implementation("io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-micrometer1-shim:1.17.0-alpha")
    implementation("io.opentelemetry.instrumentation:opentelemetry-micrometer-1.5:1.28.0-alpha")
```

My configuration:

```kotlin
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry
import io.opentelemetry.api.OpenTelemetry
import io.opentelemetry.exporter.otlp.metrics.OtlpGrpcMetricExporter
import io.opentelemetry.micrometer1shim.OpenTelemetryMeterRegistry
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.OpenTelemetrySdk
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.SdkMeterProvider
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.export.AggregationTemporalitySelector
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.metrics.export.PeriodicMetricReader
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.resources.Resource
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import java.time.Duration

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class MetricsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    fun openTelemetry(
        @Value("\${newrelic.name}") serviceName: String,
        @Value("\${newrelic.licence}") licenceKey: String,
    ): OpenTelemetry {
        return OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
            .setMeterProvider(
                SdkMeterProvider.builder()
                    .setResource(
                        Resource.getDefault().toBuilder()
                            .put(
                                "service.name",
                                serviceName,
                            )
                            .put("instrumentation.provider", "micrometer")
                            .build(),
                    )
                    .registerMetricReader(
                        PeriodicMetricReader.builder(
                            OtlpGrpcMetricExporter.builder()
                                .setEndpoint("https://otlp.nr-data.net:4317")
                                .addHeader("api-key", licenceKey)
                                .setAggregationTemporalitySelector(
                                    AggregationTemporalitySelector.deltaPreferred(),
                                )
                                .build(),
                        )
                            .setInterval(Duration.ofSeconds(MICROMETER_COLLECTION_INTERVAL))
                            .build(),
                    )
                    .build(),
            )
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun meterRegistry(openTelemetry: OpenTelemetry): MeterRegistry {
        return OpenTelemetryMeterRegistry.builder(openTelemetry).build()
    }

    companion object {
        const val MICROMETER_COLLECTION_INTERVAL = 60L
    }
}
```

When I call my service I can see that Error Rate has the same value as Throughput - even though no invalid response was returned.

I analyzed the Error Rate query:

```
FROM Metric SELECT count(http.server.requests.active.duration) AS 'Errored requests' WHERE entity.guid = '...' AND exception is not null and exception != 'None' TIMESERIES
```

and it turns out that the service sends valid requests with the exception value set as `none` instead of `None`.

I wonder if I did not configure something correctly or if there is a bug in the dashboard.

Comment: fyi: if you want to use the Micrometer API, we are recommending using Micrometer's OTLP registry: https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/otlp

Comment: I use it - see my code snippet

Comment: No you don't, you use the OTel SDK, check your imports and dependencies. :)
Check the docs I linked to better understand what you need to use Micrometer's OTLP registry.

Comment: Do you know if there's a sample code that work with New Relic?

Comment: What is in the docs should work: https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/otlp Also, if you are using Spring Boot, this is auto-configured for you, you just need to specify the OTLP ingestion endpoint.

Comment: @JonatanIvanov I noticed one small bug in OLTP registry documentation - key-value pairs do not work like `key=value` - I had to define them as: `key: value` and I made a commit on NR config https://github.com/newrelic/micrometer-registry-newrelic/commit/85d0e59fdb0047da1cd6a395239e0d58b09cfa8f , but I can't submit a PR because NR repo is archived

Comment: If you want to submit a PR for the Micrometer docs, this is the right repo: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-docs The repo you linked is not owned by Micrometer but it is owned by NewRelic.

Comment: Yes I know it's owned by NR ;) Here is the PR for the docs: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-docs/pull/330/files